# How to make the comment package work with german umlauts

Tags: german

I want to use the commentpackage with special german characters (umlauts), but it doesn't work. I get the following error message:

```
ERROR: Undefined control sequence.

--- TeX said ---
\UseTextAccent ...up \@firstofone \let \@curr@enc 
                                                  \cf@encoding \@use@text@en...
l.24   Deutsche Umlaute: äüö
```

Here is my example:

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{ngerman}
\usepackage{ascii}

\usepackage{comment}
\specialcomment{testcomment}{\asciifamily}{\normalfont}

\begin{document}

Here is a comment which works. 

\begin{testcomment}
  Test
\end{testcomment}

Here is a comment that doesn't work.

\begin{testcomment}
   Deutsche Umlaute: äüö
\end{testcomment}

\end{document}
```

Any idea, how to make this work?

**Edit**

Using

```
\renewcommand\ThisComment[1]{%
  \immediate\write\CommentStream{\unexpanded{#1}}%
}
```

after `\usepackage{comment}` solved the problem completely.

Comment: Also ASCII (and your used font) doesn't contain umlaute. You shouldn't use the ngerman package, but instead use `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}`.

Comment: @JuriRobl The `\asciifamily` font seems to contain umlauts. After aplying the answer in the other question linked above, everything seems to work as it should...